# LWC displayed in VF page without declaring resource using <aura:dependency> in Aura app

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-out

I am new to lightning out. I created a Lightning Web Component and tried to display it on a Visualforce page. My Visualforce page displays LWC even though I did not declare it in Aura app. According to my [study](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.206.0.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm?search_text=lc4vf), I should get a 404 error. How is the component displaying?

> Aura Application

```html
<aura:application  access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp" >
<!--  <aura:dependency resource="accountSearch"/> //dependency is not declared-->
</aura:application>
```

> Visualforce Page

```html
<apex:page >
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="lwcDemo" />
    <script>
    $Lightning.use("c:lwcInVisualforceapp", function() {
        $Lightning.createComponent("c:accountSearch", { // included component here 
        },
        "lwcDemo",
            function(component) {
            }
       );
    });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Check the render time... there's a good chance that it's heading to the server to get that reference, so while it works, it's slower to render. Also, it could be cached.